# My dog is not eating her food

Tags: dogs, diet, feeding, weight, can-food

My dog only likes human food, but I can't give her it, because she vomits. If she doesn't get human food, she won't eat, and is sick, because she weighs 10,5 kg and she should weigh from 16 to 22 kg. How I can feed her with dog food? I bought all possible types of dog food, but she doesn't like any of them. I need a brief answer.

Comment: please, could you provide more information? How did you change from one food to the other? Is it wet dog food or dry? (In case you change the food suddenly, maybe this answer would help: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/9592/after-how-many-days-should-i-worry-when-my-dog-will-not-eat-a-new-diet/9633?r=SearchResults#9633

Comment: Its dry food, and we everyday feed her with human food, but a bit of it.

Comment: hola nicolas, tu perro se ah acostumbrado a comer comida para humanos. Las personas de aqui te estan preguntando si les puedes dar mas informacion al respecto y tamben que les expiques si es comida seca o mojada la que le das al perro (dog food) y si el cambio fue drastico

Comment: Eso ya lo respondi hace una hora

Comment: Have you tried raw dog food? Or wet kibble? What does the sick look like? Human food is barely good for humans let alone dogs, this is not the way to go.

Comment: Yes, I already tried all kinds of dog food except the wet kibble. Thanks, I'll let you know when I have new advances

Comment: Hello, can you give me a cheap recipe to make wet dog food?

Comment: Hi, the vet recommended me a can of wet food, and he told me that I should mix two tablespoons of it with the dry food so that my dog likes the dry food, and that she should eat in the morning, so I leave her without food since noon, but no matter how hungry she is in the morning, she does not eat, only at night before going to sleep, what do I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this trick that I have been playing on my dog for quite some time and to be fair, it's kind of funny. The trick is to mix a little (not a lot) of human food into the dog's food. If you put a little and let it mix with the dog's food, it might not make the dog vomit and she will eat the food. However, be careful with what you put in there, the basic "no-nos" for cats and dogs are onions, grapes, chocolates, and ranch. Also, anything with xylitol in it is poisonous to dogs and cats.

Answer (score 5):

Since you need a brief answer, I'll make this quick.

There are some types of wet food (like Freshpet, which comes in a tube, get it  [here](https://freshpet.com/dog/deli-fresh/) This is made with mostly human food that is modified for dogs.

The next thing you can do is get a customizable recipe, which will taste good to her and also will be gentle on her stomach. (link [here](https://www.purina.com/pet-food-finder))

In the meantime, try some dietary supplements for pets to keep her healthy while she waits for her new food. Link for that [here](https://www.chewy.com/b/dietary-supplements-1569). These supplements are pretty cheap and come in chewable, powders, or creams.